# Plymouth won't load in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, boot, plymouth

I am having problems having Plymouth load on my computer.The boot messages show

```
error:unexpectedly disconnected from boot status daemon
```

The VGA output is

```
user@linux: ~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
```

I enabled the non-free repo and installed the firmwares but there was no change in the output.I use a Dell Inspirion 15 3552 with Pentium Quad Core(N300) laptop.

Comment: Have you created a new initial ram disk with `update-initramfs -u` after installing Plymouth? You will also need to edit `/etc/default/grub` and at the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` add the option splash like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and run `update-grub2` as root user.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Are you installed the `firmware-atheros` package?

Comment: I did as instructed by the plymouth installation page.I also installed the atheros package but it only removed the Bluetooth error message.Thanks for that(Will correct the output)