# Problems installing/updating Linux in Dell Inspirion 15 3552

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, boot, intel-graphics

I bought a Dell Inspirion 15 3552 laptop preinstalled with Ubuntu Linux 14.04.However since the version is old,I installed Arch Linux,but the screen goes blank(As in literal blank,not a black screen) during the boot.I did'nt think the problem was with the graphics as Arch boots to a console.

I thought it had something to do with the Arch itself and went on to re install debian.However this time it did work,the graphics was quite poor(For a laptop of its calliber) and I could'nt get Plymouth to work(As I have described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347135/plymouth-wont-load-in-debian-jessie)).

But I thought it had something to do with Plymouth,but I observed applications that used 3D acceleration would'nt load and show a 'LLVM Error'.

I tried to upgrade to the latest Linux images from Jessie backports,as described by an answer given here similar to mine but again after upgrade I again ran into the blank screen problem as described above.

I then tried to use the latest Xubuntu image to again install another OS but again I encountered the blank screen problem.(I kind of intuitively think it has to do with the Linux version).

Do note that when upgrading to the latest kernel,the terminal showed an error(modules for i915 not found) but when I inquired about the problem it had to do with SKylake processors(Mine was Intel Pentium Quad Core) so I did'nt do anything.

I checked for the factory image but it was still in Ubuntu 14.04.So I am not really interested in using that.

Comment: Have you tried installed the 14.04 factory image and then upgrading it to a more recent Ubuntu version?

Comment: I will try this

Comment: The package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` should be installed to solve the `modules for i915 not found` error ,

Comment: I did it and there was no change.Also Icould'nt find any recovery for my PC online.